# Is Twilio Voip sessions encrypted?

Tags: android, ios, voip, twilio

I'm checking Twilio as a framework for VoIP calls we would like to integrate into our mobile application (Android and iOS).
I've gone over the Android tutorial and documentation, and so far it seems awesome.
One important requirement we have, though, is that the voice media streaming is encrypted.
I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Anyone knows what the current situation and future plans on this subject are?

Thanks,
Yoram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't encrypt the data (that would require them to use SRTP, which they don't)

you can see https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip/sip-security for the Sip Security Best Practices, they offer SIP over TLS though, to prevent anyone from seeing your SIP messages, but from what I've read, the audio frames are not encrypted.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Just confirming what is above.  We *do not* offer the ability to encrypt the media (RTP), we *do* offer the ability to encrypt the signaling (SIP+TLS).

Comment: Thanks @DevinRader for the quick answer. Do you know if there are plans to support encryption in the future?

Comment: any updates on this front? looking forward to media encryption